# Why is my html not displayed with jQuery html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to jQuery so please be indulgent.

I got a variable in javascript that contains some html:

when doing `console.log(tableData);`

I get :

```
<tr class="table_row event_6163><td>Tue 16th Feb 2016</td><td>DEMO Venue</td><td>V_Town</td><td>United Kingdom</td><td class=green>Tickets available</td></tr>
```

Then I do `$('#event_stats tbody').append(tableData);`

but I don't have anything displayed. Why ? It works with some other html content. I got no error in my console

Comment: Is the missing `<` in front of your `<tr>` a typo?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: and also Did you see this `class="table_row event_6163`

Comment: no I don't have anything appended when viewing the source of the page.
Yes, as stated, "I got no error in my console"

Comment: Yes, that was it. It is weird though, cause when I have several rows, then it was ok, and when I had only one, it didn't display anything ..

Comment: You are missing a bunch of quotes: `"table_row event_6163`, `class=green>`

Comment: @The-Val I'd add an answer with that, since it seems to be the problem and you saw it first :) There's other places quotes are needed too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a quotation mark missing here:

```
<tr class="table_row event_6163>
```

it should probably be:

```
<tr class="table_row event_6163">
```

Quotation marks on the class green are also missing.

I don't know if that's caused the unwanted behavior. Unfortunately I cannot test your code since the frame is missing.

Comment: Yes, that was it. It is weird though, cause when I have several rows, then it was ok, and when I had only one, it didn't display anything .. Maybe a browser behavior ..

Comment: It might be. I know for example that firefox is genuine concering some closing tags. It will display it correctly for the most part.